# Help with simplifying this MySQL query

Tags: mysql, optimization

I'm setting up a system that tracks daily challenges for a video game.  There are 4 daily challenges and one weekly challenge.  Each challenge gets saved to a table with an id, which can be reused it the challenge is ever reused (which they are, about 22% of the time).  I've got another table to store each day's challenges, it looks like this:

date | daily1 | daily2 | daily3 | daily4 | expiration

Since challenges are reused, I'd like to be able to look up other days on which a challenge was used, by its ID.  I'm using this query right now:

```
SELECT date FROM `current_daily`
  WHERE daily1 = #
    OR daily2 = #
    OR daily3 = #
    OR daily4 = #
  ORDER BY date ASC
```

It works, but it's so clunky.  I'm trying to find a better was to run this query so I don't need all the ORs, but since it's getting information from multiple columns, it doesn't look like I can use IN().  Is there another way I could simplify this query and still get the same information?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to simply your SQL by much without restructuring your tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* use an IN to clean this up, but don't expect any performance gains from doing so.

```
SELECT date 
    FROM `current_daily`
    WHERE # IN (daily1, daily2, daily3, daily4)
    ORDER BY date ASC
```

Comment: IN does not work like this.  IN is used to select a range of values, not to select across multiple fields.

Comment: I'm not really looking for performance gains, it's not a huge project, I just want to clean up the queries a little, the one I was using was so clunky, yours is much simpler.  I'll be using it, thank you

Comment: Why the down vote?  The query works, I compared it against my current query and it returned the same exact results, and on average, it did it a few milliseconds faster.

Comment: @Brent Stewart: `IN` is nothing more than short hand for a series of `OR` statements.

Comment: My bad, I guess I have never learned that syntax for an IN statement.  I rarely search across fields, and then would most likely do an unpivot on the data. I guess that is why we come here, to learn new stuff.